# Install Julia from Anaconda or as part of JuliaPro

Tags: anaconda, julia

I want to install Julia 1.0.

I have Anaconda installed.

Information found:

In https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia, I see at the top of the page conda-forge  / packages / julia 1.0.0. Therefore they have the latest version, released on August 8th. Below, one reads: Home: http://julialang.org/. Below the title "Installers", one reads linux-64 and osx-64. (No Windows version is mentioned). To install this package with conda run: conda install -c conda-forge julia. I am a Windows user, so I cannot install Julia 1.0 from Anaconda yet.

JuliaPro can be intalled for free from https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro.html.

Question:
For when they become available, what are the relative advantages of the following procedures?: (1) Install JuliaPro independently of Anaconda or (2) Install Julia 1.0 from Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your best bet is to download the official binary from https://julialang.org/downloads/. As far as I'm aware, the Anaconda version is more or less the same (i.e. it doesn't bundle any packages or IDE). Julia itself doesn't make use of Anaconda (it has its own package manager), so there is no real benefit to installing via Anaconda.

The new JuliaPro should be available in a few weeks, and will include a bundled IDE and pre-installed packages. Until then, you can manually install the [Juno IDE](http://junolab.org/) yourself to work with the above build.

Comment: JuliaPro 1.0 is now available. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The benefit to installing via Anaconda would be to get a Julia kernel for the Jupyter Notebooks that I installed through Anaconda.